# WKWebView wont show website in device

Tags: iphone, swift, wkwebview

I have implemented WKWebView for loading URL.
The issue that I'm facing is that everything works in simulator, but when I start the application on a device (iPhone 4s iOS 9.3) it starts to load the URL, `didStartProvisionalNavigation` is called, then `didFinish` is called, but the screen only shows the web view background, and it's not showing the website.

This is how I create the web view:

```
 var webView: WKWebView?
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: createWebViewConfiguration())
         webView.backgroundColor = .clear
         webView.isOpaque = false
         webView.navigationDelegate = self
         webView.scrollView.delegate = self
         webView.load(urlRequest)
         self.view.addSubview(webView)
     //Activity indicator
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:40, height:40)
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
            UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        //Background image
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "Launch")
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    }
```

and I have this delegate methods for the URL loading

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Strat to load")
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Could this be issue only for the specific device model (4s)?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that iPhone 4s Safari vesion doen't implements some html/css/javascript feature that the page you are loading implements. Could you post the URL?

Comment: That's it, I just tried with a different URL and it works. I'm sorry I cant share the URL because of the dev process.
Any advice on how can I investigate what's causing the issue? Like what's the difference with Safari on 4s

Comment: You could check the "suspicious" properties and check the browser support in sites like W3 Scholl. But, it's a hard work...